Как написать сообщение в ветку группы телеграмм?
Пытаюсь отправить сообщение в ветку телеграмм группы - но сообщения так и не приходят.
Как это реализовать?  Думаю определенно в коде есть ошибки, но не знаю какие
import time
# Use your own values from my.telegram.org
api_id = 24373206
api_hash = '2d53fab96710e5616ce33f60492dfa30'

# The first parameter is the .session file name (absolute paths allowed)
with TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(client.send_message('me', 'Hello, myself!'))

async def main():
    while True:
  await bot.send_message(chat_id={-1002439711285}, message_thread_id={2794},text="12345")

