Как в pythonanywhere запустить перезапуск бота?
Захожу в Task,
указываю полный путь до файла -(запускаю).

В логе задачи просит указать номер телефона или токен

Захожу в Консоль - BASH, но там нет не каких запросов ввести телефона или токен.

Где мне найти этот файл, где нужно ввести телефона или токен???
Есть ли какая то возможность подвязать тот BASH , в котором я уже прошел проверку телефоном и чтобы команда на перезапуск вводилась именно в проверенной консоли. Я так понимаю, что для запуска задач на перезагрузку бота, должна создаваться новая BASH консоль - только вот она не создается после запуска задачи

А вы вручную каждый раз токен вводите? Читайте токен из файла конфигурации, или из переменных окружения, например.

У меня в коде прописан только Id  и apiHash  -- Я так понимаю что нужно токен добавить в код или к файлу добавить фаил config - где и будет прописан токен?

Ну, прямо в код - не очень хорошо, а в конфиг или переменные окружения, откуда вы его будете читать в коде - да, так хорошо.

Да, понял. Вот только у меня скрипт работает без токена - так как у него задача писать сообщения от имени человека, а не как бот телеграмм.  Как мне решить проблему автозапуска кода на pythonanywhere ? После того как их сервера обновляются через 1-2 дня, - мой код останавливается и приходится опять вводить команду в консоли на запуск.

Вот мой код https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1601143/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d1%8b-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc   Он работает сейчас нормально - вот только с перезагрузкой сереров проблем - код останавливается
